# add multiple function onchange from javascript to the same input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add multiple function onchange from javascript to the same input.
some thik like this:

```
this.el = document.getElementById(this.docID);

if(x==y)
{

 this.el.onchange += function(){ // some code }

}
if(a==b)
{

 this.el.onchange += function(){  // some code }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to chain onchange functions, you can do something like this:

```
this.el = document.getElementById(this.docID);

if(x==y) {
  this.el.onchange = function(){ // some code }
}

if(a==b) {
  var oldOnChange = this.el.onchange;
  this.el.onchange = function(){ 
    // execute previous onchange function
    if(oldOnChange) oldOnChange();

    // some code 
  }
}
```

Like this you can also decide, whether you want the old onchange function to be executed before or after the new onchange code.

Comment: For the first time in my life, I'm feeling loosely-coupled languages have also some benefits. :D By the way it was a joke. They are very much useful in other senses also. Like the way you used the variable to hold a method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the onchange attribute, you should think about using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) and the other DOM2 methods. There are some cross-browser issues which crop up (even when using the onchange attribute) so my recommendation is to use a library, such as the [jQuery change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event observer.

Using jQuery, your code example would look like this:

```
this.el = document.getElementById(this.docID);

if(x==y) {
    $(this.el).change(function() { /* some code */ });
}
if(a==b) {
    $(this.el).change(function() { /* some code */ });
}
```

Comment: i can't use jquery because of $() function name conflict

Comment: DOM Level 2 events were created [for this use case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F).

Answer (score 0):

You can't add 2 functions together, that code is wrong. There's only 1 onchange function.

So you could do something like this:

```
this.el.onchange = function() {   
    if(x==y) {
        // some code
    } else if(a==b) {
        // some other code  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I can't do these, is a compliced bussines logic behind these code

Comment: I can call from html too function:
<input type="text" id="txtID" onchange="fn1();fn2();"/>
I wont to do these from javascript

Answer (score -1):

this.el.onchange calls a main function after this calling you do comparison and calls other function

```
this.el = document.getElementById(this.docID);

this.el.onchange += functionx();

functionx() {

if(x==y) {

this.el.onchange += functionY(){ // some code }

} if(a==b) {

this.el.onchange += functionZ(){ // some code }
}
```

}

Comment: onchange becomes a function, it's not a string anymore at this point. So it won't support concatenation.